# Head First Java, Chapter 16, Be The Compiler exercise query

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have just finished reading chapter 16 of Head First Java, which is about collections and the use of generics. There is a "Be the compiler" exercise at the end of the chapter that gives 9 lines of code and the challenge is to say which lines of code will compile successfully. The lines of code given are as follows:-

```
ArrayList<Dog> dogs1 = new ArrayList<Animal>();       
ArrayList<Animal> animals1 = new ArrayList<Dog>();
List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<Animal>();
ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();     //The book says this line will not compile
ArrayList<Animal> animals = dogs;
List<Dog> dogList = dogs;
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> ObjList = objects;
ArrayList<Object> objs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

The solution states that the 3rd, 6th, 7th and 8th lines will compile but when I try to compile the lines of code myself I find that the 4th line also compiles successfully. What is more, the 6th line of code relies on the 4th line of code compiling as it references the ArrayList from line 4!

I was wondering if anyone else that has done this "Be the compiler" exercise noticed this issue while completing it or if anyone can has any idea as to why the authors would have left the fourth line of code out of the solutions even though it compiles fine.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: The 4th line is perfectly fine, if the book says that doesn't compile then that's a mistake in the book.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought, thank you very much for confirming my beliefs. I just wanted to confirm it with some more java programmers before accepting it as fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 4th line should compile. If you look at the [Confirmed Errata](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596009205) for Head First Java, it's there:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Matthew. I had no idea that that errata page existed, it is really useful and has answered a few other queries I had about some exercises and statements in Head First Java.